# Ordering categories in ggplot bar graph

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have this database, which is grouped by the variables Pres and Pres_ti.

```
Pres         Pres_ti   count       perc
1 CARD IMP      ASSE      13     0.26530612
2 CARD IMP      IAMC      34     0.69387755
3 CARD IMP      SEGPRIV   2      0.04081633
4 CARD PRO      ASSE      10     0.25641026
5 CARD PRO      IAMC      27     0.69230769
6 CARD PRO      SEGPRIV   2      0.05128205
```

I used it to make a bar plot with ggplot,

```
 ggplot(g2, aes(x = factor(Pres), y = perc*100, fill = Pres_ti, 
  fct_reorder(perc)) ) +
   geom_bar(stat="identity", width = 0.7)+
  coord_flip()
```

With that code i made a graph which shows, within each category of pres, the share of the different Pres_ti categories.

I want to order the graph in order to get in the first place the bar where Pres_ti ASSE category has the highest percentage .

For example, in my data, CARD IMP should be first since ASSE percentage is 0.26>0.25

Any idea of how can i solve this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this will do the job:

```
ggplot(g2, aes(x = reorder(factor(Pres), -perc*100), y = perc*100, fill = Pres_ti, 
fct_reorder(perc)) ) +
geom_bar(stat="identity", width = 0.7)+
coord_flip()
```

Comment: Thanks! I This code sort the bars according to the highes Pres_ti category percentage. However, it doesnt sort them by the highest Pres_ti category named "ASSE".